# Remove supported language from project

Tags: android, localization

I made an android app that supported two languages. But during the project I want to remove one language. I deleted all localized files and folders (values-de/ drawable-de/ ...)
I can run the app on my device and emulator, but when I'm starting "Export Signed Application Package" I get a lint warning, that my strings are not translated in "de".

What is the correct way to delete a no longer supported language?